# Geoserver 2.6 with ECW support

Tags: geoserver, ecw

Did read "[Geoserver 2.1.1 with ECW support](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12459/geoserver-2-1-1-with-ecw-support)"

but when I look at the link - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html, it refers MSVC installation and other vague Window binary installs. Wish there was some clear documentation around in GeoServer.
   Can anyone assist on the exact steps, including binaries to bring ECW support for GeoServer 2.6 ?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html is basically telling you that you need to make it work in gdal. The only thing that is special is the windows-unique path issue. Other than that, just build ECW support into gdal and use gdal in geoserver. Maybe you can tell us what you've already tried, maybe which OS you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to comment. I am on Windows 7 x64-bit OS. What is the version of MSVC* should I download? After downloading the MSVC, should I install/copy into a specific directory? Is the ECW*msi and the gdal*MSVC* dependent on each other. The link I am referring to as an example http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.10/native/gdal/windows/MSVC2010/

Answer (score 5):

The following instructions are based on http:// docs.geoserver.org/2.6.1/user/data/raster/gdal.html

- Geoserver: 2.6.1 (As Windows Service)
- Windows OS: 7 x 64bit
- Java: 7u67 32bit (According to instruction, using 32bit Java is required for Windows Service)

--

### Installing GDAL extension

1. Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.6.1/extensions/geoserver-2.6.1-gdal-plugin.zip
2. Extract the files to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.1\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib`

--

### Installing GDAL native librarie

**Setup GDAL Data**

1. Download http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.10/native/gdal/gdal-data.zip
2. Extract this archive to `C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data`
3. Create a `GDAL_DATA` environment variable to `C:\Program File\GDAL\gdal-data`

**Setup GDAL**

4. Download http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.10/native/gdal/windows/MSVC2010/gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010.zip
5. Extract this archive to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010`
6. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010` to your `PATH`.
7. Open command prompt, you should now be able to execute gdalinfo.  If you can't there is something wrong with your `PATH`, or do a restart.

**Update GeoServer Wrapper**

8. Open and edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.6.1\wrapper\wrapper.conf`.
9. Add the following line `wrapper.java.library.path.2=C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2010`

**Install ECW Extension**

10. Download http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.10/native/gdal/windows/MSVC2010/gdal-19-1600-ecw.msi
11. Install the package, which should installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`
12. Create a `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`

**Restart GeoServer**

Comment: Thanks a lot yilik01. Your step by step helping was great.