# GDAL configuration Geoserver 2.19.2 centos 7.9 tomcat

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, ecw

I have a Centos 7.9 installation with Tomcat 9.0.54 installed with a own service. Now i have created a GeoServer 2.19.2.war and serve it with Tomcat. That works great.

I have installed gdal 2.2.4 with the following tutorial ( https://gist.github.com/alanorth/9681766ed4c737adfb48a4ef549a8503 ) but now must i configure it with tomcat or GeoServer. What i have done already:

- configure gdal data to the installation folder /bin
- configure ld_library_path: but i think it's the wrong directory

But now i get the following error:
20-Oct-2021 16:31:57.633 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Oct-2021 16:31:58.164 WARNING [main] it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities.loadGDAL Failed to load the GDAL native libs. This is not a problem unless you need to use the GDAL plugins: they won't be enabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdaljni in java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.12.0.7-0.el7_9.x86_64/lib/]

In Geoserver -> Modules -> ImageI/O-Ext GDAL Coverage Extension :  " JNI GDAL Wrapper Version: unavailable "

Can you help me to get this working so that I can serve ecw files?

Comment: This might be useful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12459/ecw-support-in-geoserver

Comment: I'd look to fix `configure ld_library_path: but i think it's the wrong directory`